# Grafana. ALert зависает в статусе firing

Tags: postgresql, alert, grafana

Есть grafana 9.4.3 и база postgresql.
нужно сделать мониторинг, который бы выводил  дату последнего успешного события.
Всю логику перенес во вьюшку и делаю из нее запрос. Например:

`select date,value,metric from v$pays`

В случае если события давно нет, то запрос вернет три поля:

```
"date" : "2023-05-16:06:20.614Z",
"value" : 60,
"metric" : " Нет информации 60 минут . С 15:06:20 16/05/2023"
```

где date = now()

Запрос всегда вернет 1 значение, либо не вернет ничего.
Интервал проверки: now-12h
периодичность опроса: 5m
for = 0s
После создания и сохранения алерта, он успешно отрабатывает и отправляется, но затем зависает в статусе firing и дальше возможны два варианта:

1. Он больше не выходит из него никогда
2. Отправляет следующий и последующие alert через 245 минут каждый

Вроде проблема зависания должна была быть исправлена https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/53341.
Если сбросить alert, то он снова отработает корректно и снова уснет. Возможно что-то делаю не так и некорректно